# Refactor attribute to model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have painted myself in a corner.

I have a model which is defined by :

```
create_table "invoices", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "organization"
  ...
end
```

Now business rules have changed and I need an 'organization' object to be linked in its place.

I already have an Organization model. I can easily add the 'organization_id' attribute to the Invoice model and declare the association.

After the update of the model I am afraid I can no longer get to the string value of 'organization' since the 'organization' attribute will be masked by the association magic method?

So, how do I define a migration step to update the current invoices table to find_or_create_by(name: xxx>) with xxx the current string in the organization column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always can use `:read_attribute` method for your Invoice model. If you want to get attribute value:

```
@invoice.read_attribute(:organization)
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of having `organization_id` would be that you'll be calling associative data from the `Organization` model... so I'd get the `name` / other data from that if it were me:

```
#app/models/invoice.rb
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :organization
   alias_attribute :name, :location, to: :organization, prefix: true #-> organization_name
end
```

This will allow you to include `organization_id` in the `invoices` table, to which you're then able to invoke the associative data as so:

```
@invoice = Invoice.find params[:id]
@invoice.organization_name #-> "Name"
```

If you wanted to keep an *organization* field in your `invoices` table, you'd have to rename the association:

```
#app/models/invoice.rb
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partner, class_name: "Organization", foreign_key: :organization_id
end
```

Comment: Your input gave me some valuable ideas for the future.

Comment: Thanks Peter - hope it helped